# Not able to connect to service with windows account in mix mode authentication

Tags: web-services, powershell

I am trying to connect web service in mix mode/claim based environment with powershell,

Below is the sample code for your reference,

> $WebSrverUrl = "sharepoint:2013/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx"
>
> $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSrverUrl
>
> $proxy.Login("khambhati.ravi", "abcd1234")

above code works well bcoz the user i am trying with is a **FBA user** but when i try the same thing with **windows user** it fails with **PasswordNotMatch**

Thanks in advanced